# Tab between Excel worksheet cells and form controls

Tags: vba, excel

I have a worksheet in Excel 2010 that is protected and used as a form for user-fillable values.  The form contains 80 cells to be filled in and two radio button form controls to be selected.  The form consists of two pages on the worksheet that are placed side by side horizontally (horizontally is a better user experience than vertically in this situation).

To get tabbing to go through the cells on the first page and then on the second page in the desired order, I used the solution on page 4 of the thread at "http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2007-excel/establishing-enter-order-on-a-protected-sheet/e7a223f3-2dae-4c7b-a37f-1819c68be5dc".  This works excellently for regular cells.

The problem is how can I also tab to the radio buttons, which are located about a third of the way through the desired tab sequence?  Unfortunately, it's not as easy as just adding the radio button names to the TabOrder array mentioned in the thread.

I've found various threads talking about tabbing between controls, but nothing that solves tabbing from regular cells to form controls, between the form controls, and then back to regular cells.

I'm relatively new to Excel VBA programming and could really use your help.  :-)

Thanks!

Don

Answer (score 0):

I can't add a comment, so I have to put this in the answer section even though it is not really an answer:        Not sure if this is still an issue for you, but are you using Option Buttons or a Group Box. And are you using Form Controls or ActiveX.

The only thing that I have found that may help is to tab to the group itself, then use the arrow keys: "When you tab to the group, you can use the arrow keys to select the next/previous option."  and "2. You can set an accelerator key on each one by adding an ampersand (&) before one letter in the label. For example, if the label's caption is "&Next", it will appear as "Next", and Alt-N will be the keystroke that selects that option. Be careful not to choose a keystroke that opens a menu -- for example, don't pick F, because Alt-F almost alway opens the File menu."

From: http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/microsoft-access/557082-how-idiotic-no-way-tab-stop-option-button-within-group.html